# Chrome Extension: Popup appears and disappears, not able to type anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension. The extension has a menu option, one of them is Invite (in `popup.html`). When I click invite, the popup appears, but disappears quickly, in less than a second. How can I fix this?

Tried to use `return false` and just `return`, no luck.

Here's `popup.js` part:

```
var popup = {
    ready: function () {

    ...

    inviteOthers: function () {
    var users = prompt("Please enter the usernames you want to invite:", "");

    if (users != null) {
      // add users
    } else {
      // popup back
    return false;
  },

...

};
$(popup.ready);
```

Please let me know if additional info needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `prompt` occurs in the browser `window` (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp)), so its as if the user clicked out of the extension. Try using a simple text input in the popup instead: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Comment: Got it. I went outside of browser scope. Thanks!